# Homescreen is moving up and down once when entering to that page in my android app

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

After adding

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

in application of manifest.xml only home screen is moving up and down.Before It was working fine.But I need my app in full screen mode without title.
I didn't get any solution till now.
Thank you in advance

Comment: use style resource to set all the screen in full screen mode.

Comment: which android version u are using ?

Comment: Try removing android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

Comment: That is because of gridview.dats y I removed fullscreen for that particular activity

Answer (score 0):

Please Define style for all version Platform in resource or Create a base activity

and use this code to hide the tittle

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

And also please ensure that android:hardwareAccelerated="true"  for better performance

I am using these ,,, in all my application ... never such thing happens on any deice

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

  <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Comment: what is the content of that screen , please paste your snippet ... are u  using any third party library for Action Bar backward  compatibility ? . plus please mention OS and device

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

You can try it programmatically...